# Why is my variable undefined?

Tags: php

I have noticed this is a common error in `php` and i tried to search the net and i can not get my answer, I am trying to create a simpe forum and I am getting these errors

```
Notice: Undefined variable: topics in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\Students forum\view_category.php on line 83

Notice: Undefined variable: topic in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\Students forum\view_category.php on line 86
```

and this is the code on line 83

```
$topics .= "<table width='100%' style='border-collapse: collapse;'>";
```

and this is the code on line 86

```
$topic .= "<tr><td colspan='4'><hr /></td></tr>";
```

and this is my code

```
if (mysql_num_rows($res2) > 0) {
        // Appending table data to the $topics variable for output on the page
        $topics .= "<table width='100%' style='border-collapse: collapse;'>";
        $topics .= "<tr><td colspan='4'><a href='index.php'>Return To Forum Index</a>".$logged."<hr /></td></tr>";
        $topics .= "<tr style='background-color: #dddddd;'><td>Topic Title</td><td width='65' align='center'>Last User</td><td width='65' align='center'>Replies</td><td width='65' align='center'>Views</td></tr>";
        $topic .= "<tr><td colspan='4'><hr /></td></tr>";
        // Fetching topic data from the database
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)) {
            // Assign local variables from the database data
            $tid = $row['id'];
            $title = $row['topic_title'];
            $views = $row['topic_views'];
            $date = $row['topic_date'];
            $creator = $row['topic_creator'];
            // Check to see if the topic has every been replied to
            if ($row['topic_last_user'] == "") { $last_user = "N/A"; } else { $last_user = getusername($row['topic_last_user']); }
            // Append the actual topic data to the $topics variable
            $topics .= "<tr><td><a href='view_topic.php?cid=".$cid."&tid=".$tid."'>".$title."</a><br /><span class='post_info'>Posted by: ".getusername($creator)." on ".convertdate($date)."</span></td><td align='center'>".$last_user."</td><td align='center'>".topic_replies($cid, $tid)."</td><td align='center'>".$views."</td></tr>";
            $topics .= "<tr><td colspan='4'><hr /></td></tr>";
        }
        $topics .= "</table>";
        // Displaying the $topics variable on the page
        echo $topics;
    }
```

Comment: Aside the numerous correct responses below, you may want to consider breaking out of php to write your html. The way you have it would be a bad time to maintain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operator `.=` is typically used for concatenation of the right and left argument, but in this case, you do not have a left argument. You must instantiate the variable like so:

```
$topics = "<table width='100%' style='border-collapse: collapse;'>";
$topic = "<tr><td colspan='4'><hr /></td></tr>";

if( ... ) {
    while( ... ) {
        $topics .= ...
        $topic .= ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the variable first before you use `$topics .="anything"`

```
$topics =''; 
$topics .= "whatever you want"; // must have been declared before
```

So in this case, it can be like

```
if (mysql_num_rows($res2) > 0) {
    $topics="<table width='100%' style='border-collapse: collapse;'>"
    $topics .= "<tr><td colspan='4'><hr /></td></tr>";
    // rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This `$topics .=` is a shorthand for `$topics = $topics .` and if you use it the first time you use a variable, the variable is not considered 'defined'.

So you should at least do:

```
$topics = '';
$topic = '';
```

Before you start using the shorthand.

Answer (score 0):

```
$topic .= 'something';
```

Is the same as

```
$topic = $topic . 'something';
```

It effectively means:

1. take $topic,
2. join 'something' behind it
3. put the result back in $topic

If $topic wasn't used anywhere before this line, the first step fails, since the $topic variable doesn't exist yet.

First time you put something in $topic, use simple

```
=
```

instead, then you can join more stuff to it via

```
.=
```